# TSQL: Matching multiple values in single column to a distinct foreign key

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that lists the users who are in the same conversation. Eg:

```
id | conversation | user
1  |  1           |  Bob
2  |  1           |  Jane
3  |  2           |  Tim
4  |  2           |  Lily
5  |  1           |  Rick
6  |  3           |  Lily
7  |  1           |  Tim
```

I now want to check when a user wants to start a conversation with other users whether they have previously had a conversation with those other users (exclusively).

Eg. Tim wants to start a new conversation with Lily. Have those two been in a conversation before where they have been the ONLY users in the conversation? The sql query would determine that they have been in conversation 2 as the exclusive participants.

EDIT:
Here's my attempt at achieving the desired result of returning the conversation_id that has the participants exclusively conversing. *Interestingly, this attempt does return the desired result*:

```
SELECT in2.[conversation] AS cid, COUNT(in2.[conversation]) AS [matchedParticipants], (SELECT COUNT(in1.[conversation]) FROM [cInboxMembers] in1 WHERE in1.[conversation] = in2.[conversation] GROUP BY in1.[conversation]) AS totalParticipants  FROM [cInboxMembers] in2 WHERE [username] IN ('Tim','Lily') GROUP BY in2.[conversation] HAVING COUNT(in2.[conversation]) = '2' AND (SELECT COUNT(in1.[conversation]) FROM [cInboxMembers] in1 WHERE in1.[conversation] = in2.[conversation] GROUP BY in1.[conversation]) = '2'
```

In this attempt, I have listed the two users I wish to find and then listed the number of participants that should be in the exclusive conversation (which is '2') and restricted the results where the [matchedParticipants] = 2 and the totalParticipants = 2.

The part which looks seriously unwieldy is the HAVING section, because of the restriction of being unable to refer to the column aliases.

Comment: Maybe you could include an expected result and which version of sqlserver being used

Comment: Hi t-clausen.dk! I'm using MSSQL 2008. That's an excellent question as to what the expected result would be... The best outcome would be to retrieve the conversation_id that the users had previously been exclusively party to (in the example given this would be conversation: 2). Therefore, SELECT [conversation] FROM ... would be the best result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very efficient but assuming you have a table like you shown:

```
id | conversation | user 
1  |  1           |  Bob 
2  |  1           |  Jane 
3  |  2           |  Tim 
4  |  2           |  Lily 
5  |  1           |  Rick 
6  |  3           |  Lily 
7  |  1           |  Tim
```

you could get a number of participants per conversation to a temp table

```
SELECT 
    T1.Conversation,
    COUNT(*) NumberOfUsers
INTO
    #TEMP
FROM
    YourTable T1
        INNER JOIN YourTable T2
            ON T1.Conversation = T2.Conversation
            AND T1.id <> T2.id
AND T1.username = 'Tim'
GROUP BY T1.Conversation
```

then filter it again using number of participants = 1 and name = Lily

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    YourTable T
    INNER JOIN #TEMP T2
        ON T.Conversation = T2.Conversation
        AND NumberOfUsers = 1
        AND T.UserName = 'lily'
--      AND T.UserName = 'jane'
```

if you get one row he had a "private" conversation with her if you get 0 row he did not.
With this you can filter for the number you want like NumberOfUsers > 50 if you want a very public conversation...

you can even use the first select as a sub query if you don't want to use a temporary table.

This aproach can create performance issues if your table becomes to big but you can optimize it with indexes and other methods

Comment: Hi Cenas, I like your approach because it seems to be the simplest, but I agree that it doesn't look like the most efficient. I might have a tinker with your idea though.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've sort of thought this idea out; I believe it will work but you should double check. Essentially what it does is adds a row number to each conversation, by users, and it uses a table value to store the incoming user ids. It then selects any conversations where the row number is equal to the count of the users and is equal to the number of people in the conversation. The double subquery is probably unideal, and maybe a sql wiz can further optimize this.

```
CREATE TABLE #ConversationPeople
(
     ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,[conversation] int NOT NULL
    ,[user] int NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO #ConversationPeople
([conversation], [user])
VALUES
     (1,1)
    ,(1,2)
    ,(2,3)
    ,(2,4)
    ,(2,1)
    ,(1,5)
    ,(3,4)
    ,(1,3)
GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.UserList AS TABLE
    ([user] int)
GO
DECLARE @users dbo.UserList
INSERT INTO @users VALUES (3),(4)

SELECT CP_Data.*, CP.ROW
FROM (
SELECT CP.ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CP.[conversation] ORDER BY CP.[user]) AS [ROW]
FROM
 @users U
JOIN #ConversationPeople CP
ON CP.[user] = U.[user]) CP
JOIN #ConversationPeople CP_Data
ON CP.ID = CP_Data.ID
WHERE CP.ROW = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @users)
AND CP.ROW = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #ConversationPeople WHERE [conversation] = CP_Data.conversation)

DROP TYPE dbo.UserList
DROP TABLE #ConversationPeople
GO
```

Comment: You can comment line 14 in and out to see how it works. However, I suppose I should note that table valued types are somewhat vendor specific, from what I understand, so this may need to be adapted for Oracle or MySql.

Comment: Wow Chris - thanks for the effort! I'll need to get my head around it, but I appreciate your work. I'll let you know if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of this query, it would be convenient if the client could query something that looks like this:

```
conversation   AllUsers
1              Bob Jane Rick Tim
2              Lily Tim
```

(Conversation 3 just has one user, which I assume is invalid and can be ignored.)

How to accomplish this given the table structure from the question? Essentially, I want to PIVOT on an arbitrary number of columns then concatenate their values to create a space-separated list of all participants in the conversation, in alphabetical order. Unfortunately, PIVOT requires you to list each of the values you are turning into columns. Recursive CTE to the rescue:

```
CREATE TABLE Conversations (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    conversation INT NOT NULL,
    [user] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Conversations (id, conversation, [user])
SELECT 1, 1, 'Bob'
UNION SELECT 2, 1, 'Jane'
UNION SELECT 3, 2, 'Tim'
UNION SELECT 4, 2, 'Lily'
UNION SELECT 5, 1, 'Rick'
UNION SELECT 6, 3, 'Lily'
UNION SELECT 7, 1, 'Tim'

;WITH ConversationNext AS (
    SELECT C1.conversation, C1.[user], MIN(C2.[user]) AS NextUser
    FROM Conversations C1
    JOIN Conversations C2
    ON C2.conversation = C1.conversation
    AND C2.[user] > C1.[user]
    GROUP BY C1.conversation, C1.[user]
),
ConversationRoot AS (
    SELECT conversation, MIN([user]) AS [user], MIN(NextUser) AS NextUser,
        CAST(MIN([user]) + ' ' + MIN(NextUser) AS NVARCHAR(500)) AS AllUsers,
        2 AS NumberOfParticipants
    FROM ConversationNext
    GROUP BY conversation
),
ConversationRecursive AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ConversationRoot
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ConversationRecursive.conversation, ConversationRecursive.[user], ConversationNext.NextUser,
        CAST(ConversationRecursive.AllUsers + ' ' + ConversationNext.NextUser AS NVARCHAR(500)),
        ConversationRecursive.NumberOfParticipants + 1
    FROM ConversationRecursive
    JOIN ConversationNext
    ON ConversationNext.conversation = ConversationRecursive.conversation
    AND ConversationNext.[user] = ConversationRecursive.NextUser
),
Final AS (
    SELECT Conversation, MAX(NumberOfParticipants) as N
    FROM ConversationRecursive
    GROUP BY Conversation
)
SELECT ConversationRecursive.conversation, ConversationRecursive.AllUsers
FROM Final
JOIN ConversationRecursive
ON ConversationRecursive.conversation = Final.conversation
AND ConversationRecursive.NumberOfParticipants = Final.N

DROP TABLE Conversations
```

At first I though this should be done in a stored procedure that takes a table-valued parameter for the list of users, but now I think it may be easier in client code to construct a space-separated list of users in alphabetical order than to work with a table-valued parameter.

If spaces are valid characters in [user], then use something else that is not valid in a user name to separate the values.

If [user] is actually an INT, you can CAST each element to CHAR(11) when constructing AllUsers.

The CAST to NVARCHAR(500) is kind of arbitrary. Without it you will get an error that the data types on the anchor and the recursive portion do not match. You should calculate a better value than 500 based on the length of [user] and the maximum number of users that can be in a single conversation.

Comment: Hi Chris, I must admit that I was wondering if I should construct my table in that manner. Intuitively I thought the data separated approach might be best, but the CSV style (eg. Tim, Lilly, Bob, etc) for each conversation could work as well. Actually, I could use this: 
`SELECT [conversation] FROM tConversations WHERE [users] = 'Tim, Lilly' OR 'Lilly, Tim'`
Although this approach could get very unwieldy with more than 2 participants in one conversation...

Comment: @Paul I did not intend to suggest a different table design; I have edited my answer to reflect this. You are right about the order getting unwieldy. The CTE is o concatenates the users in alphabetical order

Comment: @Paul sorry for the duplicate comments, I am having a browser issue. The CTE concatenates the users in alphabetical order so that the client can do the same. There is no need to worry about all the different orders that way.